# Good ventilation for open kitchen in a studio apartment?

Tags: kitchen, air, fan, smell

I live in a typical studio apartment in US. It has an open kitchen with a range hood but the the range hood only sucks smoke from the stove to the ceiling, i.e., no outside air circulation. This is the layout of my studio:

[image: Layout]

The window and front door are the only two openings to outside. There are not windows or ventilation fans in the bathroom. I have put a window fan at the window, which points outwards.

When I cook, it creates a substantial amount of smoke. It takes a day for the odor to mostly disappear. I am afraid the window fan is not very helpful because it only allows the air between the window and the front door to circulate. The air of most part of my home, including the stove, is still dead. So, I would have to wait for the smoke to slowly diffuse to the area between the window and the front door and be removed.

What should I do to make the fresh air circulate through my whole home so that the odor could be removed quickly?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the range hood move any air outside? Or it just recirculates it inside?

Comment: @virolino it only recirculates it inside. It is simply a fan with a filter.

Comment: You need a second fan inside that only circulates air within the room. Google "air circulator fan"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two solutions. To fix this properly, you should add a duct to move the flow from the stove to outside a window or some other way out of the apartment. Since that is probably outside your reasonable area of cost/benefit, you can use your current exhaust fan, but add another fan in the room that perturbs all the air. It will not be as efficient as direct extraction via the range hood, but it will probably clear the air in around an hour.

Comment: Thanks! The first solution may not be allowed by the landlord in a rented apartment. For the second solution, how should I set up the fan so that the air flows as expected (passes through the stove)?

Comment: @qpalz Making the air pass mainly in the way you want is a PhD level project! So I suggest you just go for even mixing. Point the fan in a way that it will interrupt the current flow, but also in a direction that it will pull air in from the rest of the room. I would put it on the floor between the bathroom and countertop, or on the edge of the countertop. It should face the wall between the door and window. Imagine you are blowing at a stream of incense smoke in a way that will best mix it up with the least breath. You could even try that!

Comment: should I still have my window fan on if I put a fan at the position you suggested? If yes, should it face outwards (exhausting) or inwards (pulling in fresh air)? Thank you!

Comment: @qpalz Yes, you still need the exhaust fan. Should it blow out or in? I'm not actually clear on whether one way has an advantage, so I would let it blow out, since that is the conventional way. You will get more benefit if the fan fully fills the window (or the other parts are covered by wood/cardboard), so you reduce back-flow through the same window.

Comment: Thank you. My exhaust fan itself has a adjustable plastic board to fill the window. It leaves some slits but I fill them up with plastic bags.

Comment: My concern is that, if I put the new fan in the way you suggested, would it oppose the air flow between the window and the front door? The air flows through the window but the new fan sucks air back...

Comment: @qpalz Air flow is driven by overall pressure differences. The exhaust fan creates a small zone of low pressure behind the blades. This is what causes air to flow out. Nothing you do inside the room could eliminate this low pressure zone or reduce it substantially, except if you close/seal the door (which you shouldn't do). Don't worry about what the other fan does. The purpose is to mix the air. It will interrupt the direct stream of air in to out, but that is what you need.

Comment: Got it. It makes sense. But one more question: should I switch on the range hood? During cooking and after cooking?

Comment: @qpalz Using the range hood during cooking would be good, as it will get the smoke out of your face (which is the worst place for it to be). After, it will probably make a small but positive contribution to the general air perturbation you are going for. I'd use it if it's not annoyingly loud.

Comment: I do not have an electric socket at the position you suggested to put the new fan. Do you think putting the fan in front of my bed is helpful?

Comment: @qpalz Yes. In that case, I'd angle it more toward the door rather than straight up (in the photo).

Comment: For a 380 sq. ft room, how strong (e.g., CFM) should the fan be so that it is effective? Would Vornado 630 (CFM is 363 at high speed) works?

Comment: @qpalz Sorry, there is math that describes rate of mixing but I don't know it. If you care deeply, the search terms are "mixing problem" and "ODE" (ordinary differential equation). You don't need differential equations to use the final formula. They are for deriving the answer. I imagine you should aim for emptying the room's original air contents 99-99.9% in an hour. You can assume the fan will perhaps 50% effective (CFM) when it's struggling to pull air through your door and the hallway.

Comment: Sorry for not updating you for a long time. I did not do the calculation and just bought Vornado 630 and it arrived yesterday. It works perfectly. Smoke and odor went away in half an hour. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @qpalz I'm glad to hear that! I wouldn't have done the calculation, either, but it's comforting to know that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think a ceiling fan might help.

[image: ceiling fan]

Answer (score 0):

Obtain a free-standing folding screen to place between the door and the window.

[image: layout with folding screen]

This will divert the moving air past the cooker.

Comment: I am quite against this idea, to fill the entire building with the bad stink. Imagine what would happen if everybody did that!! Eventually sharing the bathroom stink with all neighbours also?

Comment: @virolino it's not your apartment. OP wants to ventilate through the given ventilation: door and window. Anyway you posted your own answer: it's not PC to put down other answers. But as you started it, this site is life **hacks**, not "install a ventilation system".

Comment: @virolino if I set the window fan to point outwards, I suck in air outside the door and dispatch the odor out from the window. I guess that would not affect my neighbours

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like a simple solution. The problem is how tall the screen should be so that it is effective?

Comment: Full height to prevent the air going over the top of the screen. When cooking is finished, fold it and stand aginst the wall out of the way. Perhaps you can make one cheaply if you are handy.

Comment: I failed to find one of full height... will keep an eye on it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the setup below is practically possible (depending on the items availability in the shops).

The basic idea would be to create a path to remove all "poluted" air outside.

1. The kitchen hood pushes air through the first tube into a tube in the bathroom.
2. The tube in the bathroom is thicker that the tube in the kitchen.
3. There is a vent opening at the beginning of the tube in the bathroom.
4. The tube from the kitchen goes "significantly" past this vent opening.
5. After a "while", the bathroom vent tube may have a smaller diameter.
6. At the exit from the room (to the outside world), there is an extracting ventilator.

So:

1. If only the hood ventilator is on, it will exhaust air outside, pulling some of the bathroom air also.
2. If only the outside ventilator is ON, then it will extract air from both kitchen and bathroom.
3. If both ventilators are ON, they both work together for the same thing.

This solution assumes that you are able / want to drill some thick holes for the ait tubes, one of them on the exterior wall.

NOTE: **The room may actually have a venting tube already somewhere**, in which case you only need to connect to that venting tube - at least one less drilling.

[image: sketch]

Comment: Thank you for your thought. This sounds like a huge modification and may not work for a rented apartment.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution came to my mind. You did not mention any details of the room, so I cannot tell if it is doable in your case.

The solution suggested by @WeatherVane is good, IF you change the direction of the airflow, as you stated in a comment. However, there will still be a lot of smoke in the room.

My idea would be to use flexible (maybe even extensible) tubes. Connect one end to the output of the hood, and the other end will dangle near the window. When you want to cook, just place the dangling end outside - and no smoke will travel the room freely.

It will work best if you already have some tall furniture on the wall between the door and the window. Or if you can hang the tubes somehow from the ceiling (or the upper parts of the wall).

You can use some tall supports on the floor (even DIY), to hang the tubes near the ceiling. The idea is applied for the lamp below, to "suspend" the bulb:

[image: Standard Floor lamp]